# Выбор технологии для обработки данных клиент-серверной платформы

Tags: java, веб-сервер

Нужен совет, какую выбрать технологию взаимодействий клиент-серверной среды, для обработки и получения данных? Например SOAP или RESTful

**Суть задачи**: в нашей организации много МФУ и принтеров в двух разных городах, нам нужно их мониторить (*состояние, количество распечатанных страниц, получить лог ошибок и т.д.*), есть список моделей и есть парсер (*под каждую модель свой парсер*) которые умеют получать все необходимые данные с веб интерфейса устройства.

Необходимо разработать серверную часть (*будет находится во внутренней сети и иметь возможность добавлять новые устройства с ip адресами*) и клиентскую часть (*доступ необходим из сети интернет, иметь возможность получать данные с устройств которые есть в списке на серверной части*). Так же в будущем прийдется добавлять новые парсеры под новые модели. Хотелось добавлять новые методы парсера в клиентскую часть, что бы не трогать серверную часть.

Comment: SOAP практически мёртв.

Comment: Остается RESTful или можете предложить что нибудь другое?